# If statement code - making it simpler - advice needed

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm learning C from the book Learning C programming: Modern approach and I had some trouble with task where you have to calculate the closes departure time and arrival time. So I found a question here in stackoverflow.

This one: [If statement and expressions question advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521254/if-statement-and-expressions-question-advice) (To fully understand what I'm talking about look at the original post)

This code troubled me a lot, something didn't seem right in it. If you run this code and try entering a time for example 08:25 it will show you that the closes departure time is 08:00, but that time is already passed.

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    // Flight departure times since midnight
    // 8am, 9:45am, 11:19am, 12:47pm
    // 2pm, 3:45pm, 7pm, 7:45pm
         int a = 480, b = 585, c = 679, d = 767,
         e = 840, f = 945, g = 1140, h = 1185;

    // Flight arrival times for respective departure times.
          int a1 = 616, b1 = 712, c1 = 811, d1 = 900,
          e1 = 968, f1 = 1075, g1 = 1280, h1 = 1438;

          int hours, minutes, time, t, u;

    // Get the users time

          printf("Enter a 24 hour time (hh:mm): \n");
          scanf("%d:%d", &hours, &minutes);

          time = hours * 60 + minutes;

          printf("Closest departure time is ");

       if (time <= a)
          printf("8:00am");
             else
           if (time > a && time <= b) {
            t = time - a; 
            u = b - time;
            if (t < u) {
                printf("%.2d:%.2d", a / 60, a % 60);
                    if (a / 60 == 0)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (a / 60 < 12)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (a / 60 == 12)
                        printf("pm");
                    else
                        printf("pm");
                printf(", arriving at %d:%.2d", a1 / 60, a1 % 60);
                    if (a1 / 60 == 0)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (a1 / 60 < 12)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (a1 / 60 == 12)
                        printf("pm");
                    else
                        printf("pm");
            }
            else {
                    printf("%.2d:%.2d", b / 60, b % 60);
                    if (b / 60 == 0)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (b / 60 < 12)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (b / 60 == 12)
                        printf("pm");
                    else
                        printf("pm");
                printf(", arriving at %d:%.2d", b1 / 60, b1 % 60);
                    if (b1 / 60 == 0)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (b1 / 60 < 12)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (b1 / 60 == 12)
                        printf("pm");
                    else
                        printf("pm");
            }
}
```

wouldn't it if the code looked like this (This code is 50% shorter and doesn't have any unnecessary  calculations):

```
         if (time_val < a)
    {
                    printf("%.2d:%.2d", a / 60, a % 60);
                    if (a / 60 == 0)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (a / 60 < 12)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (a / 60 == 12)
                        printf("pm");
                    else
                        printf("pm");
                printf(", arriving at %d:%.2d", a1 / 60, a1 % 60);
                    if (a1 / 60 == 0)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (a1 / 60 < 12)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (a1 / 60 == 12)
                        printf("pm");
                    else
                        printf("pm");

}
   else if (time_val < b)
              {
                    printf("%.2d:%.2d", b / 60, b % 60);
                    if (b / 60 == 0)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (b / 60 < 12)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (b / 60 == 12)
                        printf("pm");
                    else
                        printf("pm");
                printf(", arriving at %d:%.2d", a2 / 60, a2 % 60);
                    if (a2 / 60 == 0)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (a2 / 60 < 12)
                        printf("am");
                    else if (a2 / 60 == 12)
                        printf("pm");
                    else
                        printf("pm");
```

Can you guys please tell me, am I missing something here?

**ADDED**
Let me specify witch part got me confused the most

```
      if (time <= a)
          printf("8:00am");
             else
           if (time > a && time <= b) {
    //why in the hell this calculation and if condition(below) would be necessary? 
    //It messes up the whole program. try the previous script. 
    //(Don't worry about the time calculations, I made them way simpler, I just wanted to leave
    //the original script)
            t = time - a; 
            u = b - time;
            if (t < u)
```

Comment: For working with times it may be worth learning about `time.h`

Answer (score 1):

This block of code:

```
                if (b / 60 == 0)
                    printf("am");
                else if (b / 60 < 12)
                    printf("am");
                else if (b / 60 == 12)
                    printf("pm");
                else
                    printf("pm");
```

is equivalent to:

```
                if (b / 60 < 12)
                    printf("am");
                else
                    printf("pm");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can do some merging:

```
if (a1 / 60 == 0)
    printf("am"); //same output am
else if (a1 / 60 < 12)
    printf("am"); //same output am
else if (a1 / 60 == 12)
    printf("pm"); //same output pm
else
    printf("pm"); //same output pm
```

Into:

```
int hour = a1/60;
if (hour < 12)
    printf("am");
else
    printf("pm");
```

As Edsger W. Dijkstra said:

> Two or more, use a for.

(or in this case, a function).

You better define a function first:

```
int print_time (int time) {
    int hour = time/60;
    printf("%.2d:%.2d", hour, time % 60);
    if (hour < 12)
        printf("am");
    else
        printf("pm");
    return 0;
}
```

Then the final main code reads:

```
if (time_val < a) {
    print_time(a);
    printf(", arriving at ");
    print_time(a);
}
else if (time_val < b) {
    print_time(b);
    printf(", arriving at ");
    print_time(b1);
}
```

Combining the function and the final piece of code gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

> This code troubled me a lot, something didn't seem right in it. If you
>   run this code and try entering a time for example 08:25 it will show
>   you that the closes departure time is 08:00, but that time is already
>   passed.
>   … Can you guys please tell me, am I missing something here?

Yes, you are missing that requested is *the flight whose departure time is closest*, irrespective of whether it's in the past or future, as can be seen also from the example:

> *Enter a 24 hour time:* **13:15**
>   *Closest depature time is 12:47pm.,
>   arriving at 3:00pm.*

---

> ```
> t = time - a; 
> u = b - time;
> if (t < u)
> ```

This calculation does exactly what's requested - compute the absolute time differences to the earlier and to the later departure and decide which one is closer.

Answer (score -1):

You might look at using

```
printf("arriving at ....%d...%s", ...., (b/16<12) ? "am":"pm")
```

the `<cond>?x:y` construct can make this kind of 'choose one thing' code clearer