# Advice in C Programming Modern Approach 2nd Edition

Tags: c

I'm currently self-learning C using this book call 'C Programming Modern Approach 2nd Edition' Please assist with this question, basically it's a question on the "If-Else, Switch" Chapter.
Chapter 5 - If Else, Switch, Programming Projects Qn 8

The following table shows the daily flights from one city to another.

```
Departure time          Arrival time
8:00 a.m.                10:!6 a.m.
9.43 a.m.                11:52 a.m.
11:19 a.m.                1:31 p.m.
12:47 p.m.                3:00 p.m.
2:00 p.m.                 4:08 p.m.
3:45 p.m.                 5:55 p.m.
7:00 p.m.                 9:20 p.m.
9:45 p.m.                11:58 p.m.
```

> Write a program that ask user to enter a time(expressed in hours and minutes, using the 24-hour clock). The program then displays the departure and arrival times for the flight whose departure time is closest to that entered by the user:

```
**Enter a 24-hour time: 13:15
Closest departure time is 12:47 p.m., arriving at 3:00 p.m.**
```

> Hint : Convert the input into a time expressed into minutes since midnight, and compare it to the departure times, also expressed in minutes since midnight, For example, `13:15` is `13 x 60 + 15 = 795` minutes since midnight, which is closer to `14:47`. (767 minutes since midnight) than to any of the other departure times.*

I just can't seem to get the ideal code for this question. I've no idea how can I "compare" which time is the "closer" time just from using If-Else or Switch. Neither do I have any other type of answers from function or array. Please give your guidance as I've been trying to solve this for a long time.

Please do provide code so I can look at how you do it.
Thank you.

Just to be detailed: Basically how do I compare which is the closer departure time.

Comment: How is your brain working to solve this without a computer? It compares the entered time with the different available times by using a chain of if and else. Do the same.

Comment: Same question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521254/if-statement-and-expressions-question-advice

Comment: @user2000698 Do you read already in the book about arrays and structures?

Comment: @Vlad: "Please do provide code" is not an acceptable Stack Overflow question, as you well know. Your behaviour here is also unacceptable. _Again_.

Answer (score 0):

For a time before the first departure time, or after the last departure time, it should be easy even for a beginner such as you. For the other, you need to calculate the middle between the departure times, and compare the entered time with that to find the closest departure time.

For example, lets take the two departure times `11:19 a.m.` and `12:47 p.m.` Halfway between those times is `12:03 p.m.` If the entered time is before (less than) 12:03 pm, then the closest departure time is 11:19 am, and if the entered time is after (larger than) 12:03 pm then the 12:47 pm departure time is closer.

My suggestion is that you make a structure, containing the departure and arrival times, and make an array of them for the specified departure and arrival times. Then make another array, containing information about the middle times. Something like

```
struct times
{
    char *departure;
    char *arrival;
} times[] = {
    { "8:00", "10:16" },
    { "9:43", "11:52" },
    .
    .
    .
};

char *inbetween_times[] = {
     "8:51",  // Time between the first and second departure
    "10:31",  // Time between the second and third departure
    .
    .
    .
};
```

With the above system, and the above data, times before 8:51 is closest to the first departure, times between 8:51 and 10:31 is closest to the second, end so on.

I don't know it it's the best way, and it's most certainly isn't the only way, it's just the way that popped into my head first.

Comment: Same question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521254/if-statement-and-expressions-question-advice

Comment: Oh wow didn't even know you could initialize a struct right away like so.. Learning something new everyday!

Answer (score 0):

A common programming shindig is to compare the difference between two numbers.

```
#include <math.h>
if(abs(value1 - value2) < somethingYouCompareItTo)
```

That's the (mathematical) absolute difference between two numbers. ie, it removes negative values.  Slap a couple of those in a for-loop to compare it to all the values in the data structure and you've got yourself a `findClosestTime()` function.

Everyone starts at the beginning, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've handled the problem of turning an entry of hours into minutes was:

```
#include <stdio.h>int main() {
    int in, out, t;
    scanf("%d %d", &in, &out);
    printf("Entry\n%02d:%02d\nLeave\n%02d:%02d\n", in/100, in%100, out/100, out%100);

    if (out-in>=0)t = ((out/100-in/100)*60+(out%100-in%100));
    else t = ((in/100-out/100)*60+(in%100-out%100));
    printf("Duration(min)\n%d\n", t); return 0;
}
```